# Create longest distance shapefile along a net

Tags: qgis, network-analyst

I am searching the way to calculate which are the maximun distances that are possible to cover from each node (point shapefile) along a network. [image]

I mean ( in the picture bellow ) how to get the red road from the 3099 point

[image]

I am using Qgis, but a solution in Arcgis o a code PyQgis,  it´s as well welcome

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will select all upstream segments from a selected line.

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/flowTrace/

Comment: Thanks GreyHippo, but this plugins needs a segment poliline like flow origin. Instead, I have a point shapefile where all of the features are the start points. I have tried GRASS order v.net.flow but I have topology problems and I do not really know if this alogrithm will work fine for me.

Comment: I am the author of the plugin.  What if it used a point to start the selection process?  Would that be helpful to you?

Comment: Thanks again GreyHippo. I´m afraid there are many things that I would need to change in your plugin. Actually, It would be useful if the start is a point shapefile with many point features (not just one) and the output would be the longest distance that this point can cover along the net, disabled the others .